# What does it mean for a multivariable function to be in $\mathcal{C}^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $\mathcal{C}^n$ be the space of all functions continuous up to its $n$-th derivative. I understand what $f\in \mathcal{C}^n$ means if $f$ is a univariate function. However for a real function, $Df:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$ and I don't know what the notion of distance is in $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$ (is it the operator norm)? So I'm not sure if this is correct:

Let $U$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^j$. A function $f:\mathbb{R}^j\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ is in $\mathcal{C}^n(U)$ if its $n$-th derivative is continuous on $U$, i.e.

$\forall\epsilon>0$, $\forall x\in U$, $\exists\delta>0$ such that, if $\left\lVert x - y \right\rVert_{j}<\delta$, then $\left\lVert f^{(n)}(x) - f^{(n)}(y) \right\rVert_{k}<\epsilon$, where

$\mathcal{L}^n(\mathbb{R}^j,\mathbb{R}^k)$ indicates the space of $n$-linear maps from $\mathbb{R}^j$ to $\mathbb{R}^k$.

But my problem is I don't know what the metric is in $\mathcal{L}^n(\mathbb{R}^j,\mathbb{R}^k)$.

Comment: The bigger question is what $X$ and $Y$ are.

Comment: Any metric spaces, I'll edit it in.

Comment: How do you define derivatives in an arbitrary metric space?

Comment: How do you define derivatives of functions between arbitrary metric spaces? How do you define linear maps between arbitrary metric spaces?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you can't differentiate in any metric space. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Why not just demand that all partial derivatives up to order $n$ exist and are continuous?

Comment: I'm just confused whether that is the same thing as the derivative itself being continuous.